# Задача на рекурсию, нужно переписать как итерация C++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Есть задачка на C++, нужно решить рекурсивным способом и через итерацию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С рекурсией вроде справился, но вот итерацию никак немогу написать.
N і M - целые числа, результат тоже целое число.
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.
Вот код, которий написал(но он не роботает, пока не могу понять в чем проблема)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double ReactangleArea(double, double);

int main()
{
    double UserSideN, UserSideM;

    cout << "Enter n, m: " << endl;
    cin >> UserSideN >> UserSideM;

    cout << "Result: " << ReactangleArea(UserSideN, UserSideM) << endl;

    return 0;
}

double ReactangleArea(double UserSideN, double UserSideM)
{
    double result = 0;

    while(UserSideM != 0 && UserSideM != 0)
    {
        if(UserSideN == 1 && UserSideM == 1)
            result = 1;
        else if(UserSideN > 1)
        {
            UserSideN --;
            result++;
        }
        else if(UserSideM > 1)
        {
            UserSideM --;
            result++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

В моем коде результат не выводиться, был бы также очень рад если б мне подсказали в чем тут ошибка)

Comment: Не знаю нужен ли код с рекурсией, но могу его также выложить если будет нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во-первых лучше все таки считать через `int`, а то на `double` есть шансы вообще условие `x == 1` не получить (из-за потери точности)

да и формула все таки целочисленная вроде как

во-вторых попробуйте начать двигаться от `local_n = 1, local_m = 1`

1. сначала идете до тех пор, пока `local_n <= n`
2. потом идёте до тех пор, пока `local_m <= m`

код:

```
int S(const int n, const int m)
{
    int res = 1;

    for (int local_n = 2; local_n <= n; local_n++)
    {
        res = res + 1;
    }

    for (int local_m = 2; local_m <= m; local_m++)
    {
        res = res + 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: ага, понятно. Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: чуть подправил код, а то я сначала подумал, что n, m могут ниже 1 опускаться

Answer (score 3):

А проще нельзя? :)

```
int S(int n, int m) { return n + m - 1; }
```

Comment: оу, а етот метод класный.) Спасибо.

Comment: А главное, быстро работает даже при очень больших числах :)